# Excel macro to copy cell data from a worksheet and paste on another worksheet based on a certain condition

Tags: vba, excel

I have two worksheets named "Slip" and "Memo". I want to copy data from Slip and automatically add it to Memo by pressing a command button that I have made in the Slip worksheet. If one (or 2) of the entries in Slip is left blank, a message box will appear saying "All entries must be filled". After that, the entries that were filled in Slip will not be added in Memo.

So far this is the code that I have:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim SentDate As Date, Source As String, Subject As String, ReceivedBy As 
String, Mode As String

Worksheets("Slip").Select
SentDate = Range("F11")
Source = Range("E1")
Subject = Range("E2")
ReceivedBy = Range("M34")
Mode = Range("M35")
Worksheets("Memo").Select
Worksheets("Memo").Range("A3").Select
If Worksheets("Memo").Range("A3").Offset(1, 0) <> "" Then
Worksheets("Memo").Range("A3").End(xlDown).Select

End If


ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.Value = SentDate
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = Source
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = Subject
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = ReceivedBy
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = Mode
Worksheets("Slip").Select

If IsEmpty(Range("F11")) = True And IsEmpty(Range("E1").Value) = True And 
    IsEmpty(Range("E2").Value) = True And IsEmpty(Range("M34").Value) = True
And IsEmpty(Range("M35").Value) = True  Then
  MsgBox "FORM is empty."
ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("F11")) = True Or IsEmpty(Range("E1").Value) = True 
Or IsEmpty(Range("E2").Value) = True Or IsEmpty(Range("M34").Value) = True
Or IsEmpty(Range("M35").Value) = True Then
  MsgBox "All entries must be filled."
Else
  MsgBox "Successfully added to Memo"
End If
End Sub
```

What condition should I put after the message box saying "All entries must be filled." ?

Suppose Slip looks like this:

A/B/C/D/E

Date/Source/Subject/Received By/Mode

May 19/RD/Meeting/HR/Fax

May 20/RD/Meeting/HR/Fax

May 21//Meeting/HR/Fax

When I click the command button it should say "All entries must be filled" since I left the Source blank in the last row. How will I prevent the rest of the entries from adding to Memo so Memo should look like this:

A/B/C/D/E

Date/Source/Subject/Received By/Mode

May 19/RD/Meeting/HR/Fax

May 20/RD/Meeting/HR/Fax

It didn't add May 21//Meeting/HR/Fax since I left a cell blank in the Slip worksheet. How's the condition for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You probably want to add an `Exit Sub` statement.  (P.S. `IsEmpty(x) = True` can be written just as `IsEmpty(x)`.  `IsEmpty` returns either `True` or `False` so your conditions will be either `True = True`, which evaluates to `True`, or `False = True`, which evaluates to `False` - so the `= True` part isn't adding any value.)

Comment: @YowE3K Hey thanks, I edited the post cause it seems like I didn't explain it well the first time

Comment: You probably want to add an `Exit Sub` statement.  **And** move the updating of the cells to **after** you have checked the validity of the source data.

Answer (score 2):

```
I think the code would be like bellows,

    Sub test()
    Dim vAddress, strAddress As String
    Dim Ws As Worksheet, toWs As Worksheet

        Set Ws = Sheets("Slip")
        Set toWs = Sheets("Memo")

        vAddress = Array("f11", "e1", "q3", "e3", "m34", "m35", "f12", "a11", "c11", "g11", "h11")
        strAddress = Join(vAddress, ",")

        With Ws
            If IsEmpty(.Range("F11")) = True And IsEmpty(.Range("E1").Value) = True And _
               IsEmpty(.Range("O3").Value) = True And IsEmpty(.Range("E3").Value) = True And _
               IsEmpty(.Range("M34").Value) = True And IsEmpty(.Range("M35").Value) = True And _
               IsEmpty(.Range("F12").Value) = True And IsEmpty(.Range("A11").Value) = True And _
               IsEmpty(.Range("C11").Value) = True And IsEmpty(.Range("G11").Value) = True And _
               IsEmpty(.Range("H11").Value) = True Then
              MsgBox "FORM is empty."
            ElseIf IsEmpty(.Range("F11")) = True Or IsEmpty(.Range("E1").Value) = True Or _
                   IsEmpty(.Range("O3").Value) = True Or IsEmpty(.Range("E3").Value) = True Or _
                   IsEmpty(.Range("M34").Value) = True Or IsEmpty(.Range("M35").Value) = True Or _
                   IsEmpty(.Range("F12").Value) = True Or IsEmpty(.Range("A11").Value) = True Or _
                   IsEmpty(.Range("C11").Value) = True Or IsEmpty(.Range("G11").Value) = True Or _
                   IsEmpty(.Range("H11").Value) = True Then
              MsgBox "All entries must be filled."
            Else
                toWs.Range(strAddress).Value = .Range(strAddress).Value
              MsgBox "Successfully added to Memo"
            End If
        End With
    End Sub
```

The code can be changed like this

```
   Sub test2()
    Dim vAddress, strAddress As String
    Dim Ws As Worksheet, toWs As Worksheet
    Dim rngDB As Range, n As Integer, k As Integer
        Set Ws = Sheets("Slip")
        Set toWs = Sheets("Memo")

        vAddress = Array("f11", "e1", "q3", "e3", "m34", "m35", "f12", "a11", "c11", "g11", "h11")
        strAddress = Join(vAddress, ",")
        With Ws
            Set rngDB = .Range(strAddress)
            n = rngDB.Cells.Count
            k = WorksheetFunction.CountA(rngDB)
            Select Case k
            Case 0
                MsgBox "FORM is empty."
            Case Is < n
                MsgBox "All entries must be filled."
            Case Else
                toWs.Range(strAddress).Value = .Range(strAddress).Value
              MsgBox "Successfully added to Memo"
            End Select
        End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: nice on the second edit, I was just about to post it :)

Comment: @ShaiRado: Thanks!

Comment: @Dy.Lee  
Hello, I tried your code and it didn't work :( but I edited the post to provide more context, can you check it out? Thanks a lot

Comment: @auqnabeshie: sorry , there is  mistyping. "q3".   in vAddress = Array("f11", "e1", "q3", "e3", "m34", "m35", "f12", "a11", "c11", "g11", "h11"). Please, change "q3"  to "o3".